typescript import & module resolution
I am developing an extension for VSCode and, coming with .NET background, would like to keep the code base structured well and keep each interface/class in their own file:
- src
  - logging
      ilogger.ts
      iloggerFactory.ts
      loggerFactory.ts

File /src/logging/ilogger.ts:
import * as winston from "winston";

export const ILogger = Symbol('ILogger');
export interface ILogger extends winston.Logger { }

File /src/logging/iloggerfactory.ts:
import { ILogger } from "./logger";

export const ILoggerFactory = Symbol('ILoggerFactory');
export interface ILoggerFactory { 
  createLogger(className: string): ILogger;
}

This works, but requires adding import to a specific file in each place that uses anything from the logging directory:
import { ILogger } from './logging/ilogger';

This is less than ideal, as i would like 'logging' to act something akin to a namespace from C#.
This is where /src/logging/index.ts comes in:
import { ILogger } from './ilogger';
import { ILoggerFactory } from './iloggerFactory';

export { ILogger, ILoggerFactory };

Now for the most part I can write:
import { ILogger, ILoggerFactory } from './logging';

However, it seems that you get different symbols imported depending on the location of a file you write imports in:
File: /src/bootstrapper.ts
import { ILoggerFactory as logging_ILoggerFactory } from "./logging";
import { ILoggerFactory as factory_ILoggerFactory } from "./logging/iloggerfactory";

console.log(logging_ILoggerFactory === factory_ILoggerFactory ); // outputs 'false'

File: /src/logging/loggerFactory.ts:
import { ILoggerFactory as logging_ILoggerFactory } from ".";
import { ILoggerFactory as factory_ILoggerFactory } from "./iloggerfactory";

console.log(logging_ILoggerFactory === factory_ILoggerFactory); // outputs 'true'

I mean, I just want to use /src/logging/index.ts everywhere, but I can't because /src/logging/loggerFactory.ts can ONLY import ILoggerFactory from /src/logging/iloggerfactory.ts.
Ideally I would like console.log(logging_ILoggerFactory === factory_ILoggerFactory); be true and import ILoggerFactory from index.ts regardless of the location.
What I am doing wrong? Is there a true typescript way of doing this?

It appears that the out dir was dirty. Cleaning it manually & running npm run compile seems to have solved the problem. I still do not understand the mechanics

Are you perhaps running into circular dependencies?
I think this "OOP-first" style of organizing code might not be the best choice for TypeScript. Things like interfaces do exist here, but are not quite fully implemented as you'd expect in .NET or Java.
Here's what I would do:
File src/logging.ts
import * as winston from "winston";

export const LoggerFactory = {
  function createLogger(className: string) {
    return winston.createLogger({
      // logger options go here
    });
  }
}

This lets you import the factory like this:
import { LoggerFactory } from 'src/logging'

const logger = LoggerFactory.createLogger("MyClass")

Note that both LoggerFactory and logger will be typed implicitly, because winston.createLogger has been type-annotated by the authors of the winston library.
This is quite useful because you're writing type-safe code even though you didn't specify a single type yourself -- TypeScript is doing the work for you here.

"type-annoted" doesn't really work here; both "type-annotated" or "type-anointed" could be close, although I'd favor the first one...

Nah.. It was some weird crap with rubbish in the out dir. After I cleaned it, everything went back to normal.
